# How could I connect a PDIP8 PIC controller to a PCB so I could remove it?

Tags: pic, connector, header

I would like to not solder it in place so I could simply remove it for reprogramming. Is there breadboard-like PCB solderable component which will let me stick the MCU to it and then easily remove it?

I tried [Arduino-like headers](https://www.devobox.com/en/headers/29-pcb-header-stackable-1x8p-for-arduino.html), but they are way too big and make the PIC wobble without electrical contact.

I'm sure there is such thing but I don't know the name.

Comment: Is in-circuit programming not an option, in case you haven't heard of that yet?

Comment: `Is there breadboard-like PCB solderable component`  - yes, they're called sockets

Comment: Seriously consider in-circuit programming (as appropriate for your mcu) even if it means a bootloader.  Not only more convenient now, but makes firmware upgrades later a breeze compared to 'difficult' or 'impossible' if you have to get at the chip iteself. (I'm guessing this is hobby work, and hobby projects in my experience get lots of firmware upgrades---but maybe you're more diligent about doing a proper development process than I am).  If this is a hobby project, consider a bootloader (if required) + usb port for the programming.  You may lose your programmer, but you won't lose usb.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [8-position DIP socket](https://www.digikey.com/short/8t5f8849).

[image: *-DIP socket]

{Digikey}

Comment: [link](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgoat.com.au%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F10%2Fthank-you.gif&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=681d9b283894e4ca25d05eb3bee7ee775765eb3bf37d09d7aa82218414ce3097&ipo=images) Thank you.

Comment: If you are really into it, use three DIP sockets: First one soldered to the board, second one is sacrificial and left in the on-board socket, third one sacrifial as well and left on the PIC. You can do quite a few inserts/removal and once the two sacrifical DIP sockets are worn down, simply change them.

Comment: Also, don't use the type of socket shown? As I understand, the turned-pin style is more durable.

Comment: @Matthew: Machine-pin sockets are more reliable in situations where chips will be changed very rarely.  Well-made dual-leaf sockets remain pretty reliable through hundreds of swaps, though some lesser quality sockets--especially single-leaf ones--may be flaky from the get-go.

Comment: @Matthew I don't know which is more reliable, but I developed a pretty good dislike for machine-pin sockets: I was always bending pins in machine-pin sockets, but rarely in leaf sockets.

Answer (score 11):

Putting the IC repeatedly in and out of a DIP socket would damage the IC pins too much, so I'd consider that a no. Even levering it out carefully with a tool, I'd say you'd get about 10 insertion/removals before the ICs and sockets aren't what most factories call production standard any more. 8-pin DIPs are short and thick so one-side-other-side gradual levering still noticeably bends the pins. And this is for development where there's plenty of removals and often with much less care than that.

A ZIF socket would be ideal but 8-pin DIP ZIF sockets aren't made. The smallest ones are 16-pin. But you could use a 16-pin ZIF and just use the leftmost or rightmost 8 pins.

Something I did a lot in development was:

- Put an IC socket on the PCB for the microcontroller (MCU)
- Solder a ZIF socket onto a turned pin IC socket
- Plug the resultant ZIF assembly into the socket

I'd use the ZIF socket in the ZIF assembly until the development was over. After that, I'd plug the MCU directly into the board IC socket.

You could do that here, using the 16-pin ZIF and soldering 8 of its pins onto the top of an 8-pin turned-pin IC socket.

Comment: FWIW I've done *way* more than 10 removal-reinsertion cycles on 8-pin (and larger) mcus when I was too cheap to buy a zif socket.  With care---remove by sliding a thin screwdriver under the cenre as a wedge---it can be done.  Nowadays I'd go your way, but everything I've done recently was programmable in circuit.

Comment: @2e0byo: Ditto.  WAY more than ten.  Probably more than 100 in some cases.  The thing I found most useful was one of the metal pieces that sat in the ends of unused PC card slots.  Those had a notch that was perfectly placed to allow sliding the end under a 0.3" DIP and rocking back slightly.  Do that to lift one of the chip a little bit, then the other end to lift almost completely out, and then the first end to lift completely out.  Probably about 5 seconds, for consistent removal with no bent pins.

Comment: @2e0byo, I don't mean 10 or so until the IC breaks (I'll reword it to make that clear), I'm mean not many until the ICs get tired pins and aren't anything like production standard any more. That's my experience and I certainly did a lot of IC removal from sockets with this, with 8, 16, 20, 24, and 40-pin packages in decent turned-pin sockets. The longer ones, like 24 and 40-pin, were easier because it could be more gently angled up in a series of lifts. But, even with great care, the short and thick 8-pin was more severe angling so the pins bent more each time. I used a lot of 8-pin EEPROMs.

Comment: The point about tired pins is worth making. Also tired sockets.  Nothing more annoying than one pin not making electrical contact but looking fine.   @supercat I never thought of that, not a bad idea.

Comment: Machine-pin sockets require almost perfect IC pins, and pins can't be swapped much before they become unsuitable for machine-pin sockets.  When using leaf-spring sockets, however, chips can be good for many dozens of insertions if handled carefully.

Comment: @supercat, yeah, there's lots of slower and riskier ways. Or use the ZIF socket solution we used and get no wear, no excessive care needed playing with gentle tool levering, very fast removal that anyone and everyone can do risk-free, and a board sockets and ICs left at production standard. Which is much simpler and what we all did for at least a decade. I worked on boards a long time, we tried all different ways on our way there.

Comment: @TonyM: Not all boards have space for ZIF sockets.  Good leaf-spring sockets work well enough for hundreds of insertions, and even chips can last for many dozens.

Comment: @supercat, you can see that the IC socket lifts the ZIF above the board for clearance, though. If it wasn't enough, we'd just stack a few more IC sockets under the ZIF, it's so easy and worked great with fast ICs. I fully understand the way you're advocating, I've done lots of it. But the ZIF assembly beat the 'careful surgery' IC socket option. Instead, anyone could use this with no damage. Sw/hw/mech engineers, test staff, managers - anyone.

Comment: @TonyM: What happens if you have two or more sockets without much space between?

Comment: @supercat, never had that, seen no boards over a lot of clients where anyone needed two regularly socketed devices like that. If it did arise somewhere then we'd be forced to put up with all the disadvantages of the board surgery version, I imagine. But surely this is just inventing a situation to try and unearth a disadvantage, it's not the vast majority of cases. I think we may start to go round in circles here...I think you've got a position on this, whatever I present, which is OK. For me, I can't undo a pretty long and varied experience of this. I'll leave it there and wish you well :-)

Comment: @TonyM: A lot of systems I've worked with had software that was too big to fit in a single EPROM.  While ZIF sockets were nice, probably less than half of the insertions and removals I've done in my career have involved them because few devices would undergo enough insertions and removals to wear out a decent leaf-spring socket, or required ensuring that device pins be left in sufficiently pristine condition to work with machine-pin sockets.

Answer (score 7):

Simple, a DIP socket of the same size, or a ZIF socket för programming.

Comment: @OP If you use a DIP socket, make sure there is enough space at the ends of the chip to get a lever in to remove it, and if using a ZIF socket make sure there is enough space for the lever.

Comment: I'm not sure they make 8 pin ZIF sockets.

Comment: I was thinking about ZIF, but they cost too much.

Comment: @GodJihyo I'm not sure either, but the bigger ones **could** be used. I much doubt OP want that though.

Answer (score 5):

In the past have used something like an [Eject-A-DIP](https://www.arieselec.com/product/12024-dip-collet-solder-tail-socket/):

[image]

The features of which the manufacturer says are:

> - Eject-A-DIP™ is a rugged, solderable socket with a unique ejector/latch for fast in-field board maintenance
> - The latch locks in the connector or device, making it ideal for high vibration environments
> - The latch, when used as an ejector, removes DIP packages without pin damage

That was when using a 40 pin DIP PIC which stored it's program in EPROM, and therefore before re-programming had to remove the device to place in a UV eraser.

Not sure if such sockets are available in 8 pin DIP style.

Comment: That is not a ZIF socket. And it doesn't come in DIP-8 size.

Comment: @DavideAndrea You are correct that it is not available in DIP-8 size, and I omitted to check that before answering. Should I delete this answer as the question specifically specified "PDIP8"?